# How to sort a list of objects according to two parameters to compare at Java?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, binary-search, comparator

I have a class like that:

```
public class Zern extends Something{
 private int costA;
 private int costB;

 public int getcostA() {
     return costA;
 }

 public void setcostA(int costA) {
     this.costA = costA;
 }

 public int getcostB() {
     return costB;
 }

 public void setcostB(int costB) {
     this.costB = costB;
 }
}
```

I have a list that holds that kind of objects:

```
private List<Zern> zerns = new ArrayList<Zern>(MAX_ZERN_SIZE);
```

I will add new objects to my list however I always want to have a ordered list according to cost a and if there is an object at list which has the same cost with my object that I want to add I want to add that object according to their costB.

***I mean:***

```
Index of objects at list   0    1    2    3    4   5
CostA                     10   15   22   22   25  36
CostB                     26   12   17   19   23  44

If I want to add an object that has a costA 22 and costB 18, 
it will locate at index 3.
```

How can I do it effectively (because I will add an object to a sorted list so it means that I can use **binary search** - if it is possible I want to find a solution according to that) with **Comparator** or something like that?

Comment: Exactly, you'll need to implement a custom Comparator. Here's an [example](http://www.javadeveloper.co.in/java-example/java-comparator-example.html).

Comment: You could also use a TreeSet with a custom comparator so that the collection remains sorted, and has 'binary search'-like lookup.

Comment: For tree set it says: "This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the basic operations (add, remove and contains)." also Comparator can be used for them. I see that it is so powerful but what is the good sides of array list over tree set otherwise tree set looks perfect?

Comment: You cannot access an item via its index as in a arraylist implementation. If you do not need it you should go with a sorted set.

Comment: The zends list will not have any objects at first so I will add objects them from 0 to a limited number. Also I want to get the less cost object(according to costA, if equals with any other costB) at any time. These are my needs, I will not fill the list and after that sort it, it will be sorted every time cos I will add objects by order. So how can I find a solution?(maybe with TreeSet and comparator)

Answer (score 4):

Use `Collections.sort` with the following comparator:

```
Collections.sort(zerns, new Comparator<Zern>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Zern z1, Zern z2) {
        if (z1.getcostA() == z2.getcostA()) {
            return z1.getcostB() == z2.getcostB() ? 0 : 
                z1.getcostB() < z2.getcostB() ? -1 : 1;
        } else {
            return z1.getcostA() < z2.getcostA() ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }
});
```

**Update:** If you do not need indexed access to your items you may want to use a sorted set implementation from the first place with a custom comparator:

```
TreeSet<Zern> zerns = new TreeSet<Zern>(new Comparator<Zern>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Zern z1, Zern z2) {
        if (z1.getcostA() == z2.getcostA()) {
            return z1.getcostB() == z2.getcostB() ? 0 : 
                z1.getcostB() < z2.getcostB() ? -1 : 1;
        } else {
            return z1.getcostA() < z2.getcostA() ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }
});
```

Now objects can be added and your set will always remain sorted (note: I added a constructor and toString to your Zern class):

```
zerns.add(new Zern(10, 26));
System.out.println(zerns);     // => [(10,26)]
zerns.add(new Zern(22, 19));
System.out.println(zerns);     // => [(10,26), (22,19)]
zerns.add(new Zern(22, 17));
System.out.println(zerns);     // => [(10,26), (22,17), (22,19)]
zerns.add(new Zern(15, 12));
System.out.println(zerns);     // => [(10,26), (15,12), (22,17), (22,19)]
```

You can remove an item

```
zerns.remove(new Zern(22, 17));
System.out.println(zerns);     // => [(10,26), (15,12), (22,19)]
```

or remove the worst cost item

```
zerns.remove(zerns.last());
System.out.println(zerns);     // => [(10,26), (15,12)]
```

or get the best cost item via

```
System.out.println(zerns.first());    // => (10,26)
```

Comment: When I add elements to that list it means that the list will be sorted anytime. If I call Collections.sort(..... every time that I add an object to that list does it rearrange it? How I can use binary search with that comparator to get more efficiency?

Comment: If you want your collection to stay sorted after each add operation, use TreeSet with this custom comparator.

Comment: @kamaci Instead of an ArrayList you may use a [TreeSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) instead.

Comment: @Howard I wrote a comment to my question.

Comment: Can you show an example how I will add, get and remove elements. For example I will loop this list until their best cost and I want to remove worst 5 cost objects at every loop so how can I implement it?

Comment: +1 on using a TreeSet. Insertion will be slower to sorted sets, but they will always be sorted. You have to weigh how often you insert vs. how often you need to sort. Also, see my comment on Isaac's answer re. comparisons on ints.

Comment: Voting up for your answer. Just one thing to learn how about the sorted set implementation of it and adding and element to that set is costs log(n) or more?

Comment: @Java Drinker You're perfectly right. I just edited my comparators.

Comment: @kamaci The treeset is backed by a red-black tree. You find more details in this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree).

Comment: @Howard Thanks for the reply that the idea behind the TreeSet. I want to randomly select to object from that list so I need(I think I need) an index based system for it. Is it possible to reach an object at a TreeSet?

Comment: @kamaci - You can't both randomly select an element, and always have the structure sorted for the same data structure. If you need this kind of functionality, you will either need to keep a List, and sort a copy of when required, or keep 2 separate data structures, and keep them consistent. You could always extend TreeSet to store your indexed list within, and maintain consistency that way, but the whole requirement seems suspect here...

Comment: @Java Drinker, actually I don't want to fill the list and after that I want to sort it. I want that when I add an element to my list, it should find it's correct place and locate that index with less effort. Also I should reach them by index. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Just compare the first criteria. If they match, compare the second criteria:

```
public int compareTo(Zern other) {
   final int result;

    if (this.costA == other.costA) {
        if (this.costB > other.costB) {
            result = 1;
        } else if (this.costB < other.costB) {
            result = -1;
        } else {
            result = 0;
        }
    } else {
        if (this.costA > other.costA) {
            result = 1;
        } else if (this.costA < other.costA) {
            result = -1;
        } else {
            result = 0;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Just as an additional note, it is a bad idea to just use subtraction to compare Integers. In the case of a=Integer.MIN_VALUE and b=10, for example, you will get a positive result, even though a is clearly much less than b. The correct way would be to check if a[<,=,>]b and return [-1,0,1] accordingly

Comment: @java drinker Fair enough. Updated.