# Adding an Element to Automatically Correct Place According to its Cost Ascendingly with most Performance

Tags: java, performance, collections, set, comparator

I had a question previously: [How to sort a list of objects according to two parameters to compare at Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778433/how-to-sort-a-list-of-objects-according-to-two-paramaters-to-compare-at-java)

Now I want to do that:

`I will define a list and when I add en element it it will find the correct place for it according the its cost. (I don't want to generate a list that has unordered elements and sort them after that)`

I want to do that with most performance. I mean my list will be ordered everytime so when I want to add an element o that list it will be an adding to an ordered list. Cost of ordered list may be O(logn) with finding the correct place with binary search(even finding the place maybe with less cost, adding element to that list(i.e. an ArrayList) may require more cost than its benefits so you can suggest adding element without binary search implementation if you think that using that class(ArrayList, etc. etc.) is not good at *total*)

Answer (score 1):

You can use TreeSet (which O(log n) insert and O(1) remove first) or PriorityQueue (which is O(1) insert and O(log n) remove first)

Note: TreeSet is sorted as you insert, PriorityQueue is not.

The only way to avoid an O(log n) operation is to make some strict assumptions about the range of possible values which unlikely to be helpful here.

Comment: I want to work on a index based class, I mean I want to retrieve an element by get(index), what do you suggest according to that needs?

Comment: IMHO indecies are only meaningful if they don't change for an element. i.e. get(5) should always return the same element. I suspect you should be using a lookup which doesn't move around when an element is added, without more details of why you want a low order indexed/sorted collection, it is hard to say.

Comment: Actually I want to implement this at my genetic algorithm to hold genes. I will add new genes to my geneList at every generation and I will remove some number of worst genes from my geneList too. However I want to do mutation at my geneList so it means that I have to select a gene randomly and should know what is the index of it(its index may change at the end of this generation it doesn't matter)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, you may be wright about indecies, how to randomly select an element from a TreeSet?

Comment: In thats case, ArrayList is the only one which will give you efficient random access. If this is a requirement, you have to use it.  For insert you can do a binary search as you suggest.  There is no collections does O(1) for all accesses types (otherwise you wouldn't need more than one ;)

Comment: So do you mean that ArrayList with adding binary search is the most logical think to do?

Comment: The only way to use TreeSet and have efficient random acces is to maintain a copy of the TreeSet in an array.  This is fine if you have a high read/write ratio. (Which I doubt)

Comment: Yes. If you have very long collections, you may need to create your own structure of List<List<?>> to avoid the cost of insertion. But I wouldn't worry about this until it shows as an issue in your profiler.

Comment: What do you suggest to maintain an array of a TreeSet and with it? And all in alll which one is the best for my case, using arrayList with binary search or TreeSet with a copy of it in a array?